# Jenkins build failing to push code to GIT

Tags: git, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, git-push

Jenkins build is failing to push to GIT 
Error msg is :-

> - git push --tags origin develop To ssh://alm.oraclecorp.com:2222/epm_pbcs_15318/pbcs.git  ! [remote
>     rejected]       develop -> develop (Update requires 'Merge-Request'
>     line present in the commit-message.) error: failed to push some refs
>     to 'ssh://****@alm.oraclecorp.com:2222/epm_pbcs_15318/pbcs.git'

```
    stage('Push')
    { 
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'gitlogin', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
        //sh("git tag -a some_tag -m 'Jenkins'")
          sh('git push --tags origin $BRANCH_NAME')
        }
        if ("${BRANCH_NAME}"=="develop" || ("${BRANCH_NAME}".startsWith("release")))
        {    
            sshagent (credentials: ['GitSSHLOGIN']) {
                       // sh("git tag -d PSTEST ")
                          sh("git tag -a PBCS_${BRANCH_NAME}_${ReleaseNumber}_${BUILD_NUMBER} -m 'Tag the build PBCS_${BRANCH_NAME}_${ReleaseNumber}_${BUILD_NUMBER}'")
                          sh('git push --tags origin $BRANCH_NAME')
```

Comment: Please take a few moments and properly format your code, by adding four or more spaces to each line of code to make it monospaced.

Comment: It looks like @jon may have been copy and pasting commands and output from a terminal (I'm not sure), and code blocks often don't format correctly on SO for some reason. I found that using triple-backticks are frequently more consistent.

Comment: I have formatted the code now. Could you please suggest the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the "develop" branch in your remote repository has merge restriction
(possibly for Code review approval) before MR can be merged.
This should be configurable in your remote repository admin page

you should probably have options like : Open , Requires Review, Private ,Frozen
etc for your branch

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your remote is set to only accept tags poiting to commits having a specific commit message :

> Update requires 'Merge-Request' line present in the commit-message

It looks like it's a way to ensure that builds have gone through the intended workflow (merge requests).